# show action sheet, but not animated

Tags: iphone, animation, uiactionsheet

How can I show an UIActionSheet without any animation, so that it just show up?

Thanks in advance.
Sean

Answer (score 0):

Action sheet is designed to show buttons in animation fashion.So it cant be changed.